# Pandas: unmelt dataframe to add arbitrary number of columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe `df` in Pandas that looks like this:

```
stores           product           discount
Westminster      102141            T
Westminster      102142            F
City of London   102141            T
City of London   102142            F
City of London   102143            T
```

And I'd like to end up with a dataset that looks like this:

```
stores           product_1  discount_1 product_2  discount_2 product_3  discount_3
Westminster      102141     T          102143     F       
City of London   102141     T          102143     F          102143     T
```

How do I do this in pandas?

I think this is some kind of pivot on the `stores` column, but with multiple . Or perhaps it's an "unmelt" rather than a "pivot"?

I tried:

```
df.pivot("stores", ["product", "discount"], ["product", "discount"])
```

But I get `TypeError: MultiIndex.name must be a hashable type`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape, only necessary create counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), last change ordering of second level and flatten MultiIndex in columns by `map`:

```
df = (df.set_index(['stores', df.groupby('stores').cumcount().add(1)])
        .unstack()
        .sort_index(axis=1, level=1))
df.columns = df.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
df = df.reset_index()
print (df)
           stores discount_1  product_1 discount_2  product_2 discount_3  \
0  City of London          T   102141.0          F   102142.0          T   
1     Westminster          T   102141.0          F   102142.0        NaN   

   product_3  
0   102143.0  
1        NaN
```

Comment: Wow, amazing! Thanks.

Comment: I can follow most of this, but what are the brackets around the initial assignment doing? `= (df.set_index...))`

Comment: @Richard - only because multiple line command, if use one line code it should be omit

Comment: Didn't know that! Thank you.